# Hero HTML5 videos - can playback start before DOMcontentloaded?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Probably a silly question but are there any ways to force playback of a HTML5 `<video>` earlier than the DOMcontentloaded event?

The video is hardcoded in a liquid file with the following attributes:

```html
<video
  poster="./poster.webp"
  src="./545645660.sd.mp4"
  loop muted playsinline autoplay preload="auto" type="video/mp4" disableRemotePlayback>
</video>
```

Since it's a hero background video, it needs to start playback as fast as possible but there's about a 2 second delay which looks bad. I've found that disabling JavaScript in Dev Tools will make it load instantaneously so it appears the large amounts of scripts are causing the delay but not sure if there's a way to prioritize playing back the video.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to delay videos downloading u til after all the JS, CSS, HTML, images - since these are required to load the page.  Perhaps you can defer some of the scripts to load later?

You could also remove the poster - since that downloads BEFORE the video, and is probably never seen - as the video autoplays.